# Bigquery String Type and Repeated mode column value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to read the string type and repeated mode column value into multi-row records,
This is the current table structure with data ( "Tags" is the column with string type and repeated mode)

This "tags" column is under the "child_events" column which in RECORD type

[image]

My expected output is

[image]

I tried a few options but still not working

```
SELECT id,tags
from (
select b.id ,b.tags
FROM  ticket_table a, UNNEST(child_events) b
) as b , UNNEST(tags) where b.id=15927
```

But this above is not working as expected

The output that I am getting from the above code

[image]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`your_table\`, UNNEST(Tags)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH ticket_table AS (
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      '3777698' ticket_id,
      '15927' id, 
      ['automated_email', 'complaint_no', 'dis_misc_spam'] Tags
  ) child_events
)
-- query starts here
SELECT e.id, tag 
  FROM ticket_table, UNNEST(child_events) e, UNNEST(e.Tags) tag;

-- query result
+-------+-----------------+
|  id   |       tag       |
+-------+-----------------+
| 15927 | automated_email |
| 15927 | complaint_no    |
| 15927 | dis_misc_spam   |
+-------+-----------------+
```